# Programmatically drawing custom oval shape on screen swift

Tags: swift, uikit, draw

How can i draw custom oval shape like in below image in swift (not swiftUI).

Thank you in advance
[image]

Comment: Look for UIBezierPath, a rectangle with corner radius in your case should be enough.

Comment: can you please share some code snippets? that would help me so much

Comment: you can just use cornerRadius ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tried to clone similar view using UIView and was able to create similar UI as you have stated on screenshot [image]

And here is my code snippet

```
let width: CGFloat = view.frame.size.width
let height: CGFloat = view.frame.size.height

let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height), cornerRadius: 0)
let rect = CGRect(x: width / 2 - 150, y: height / 2.5 - 100, width:  300, height: 400)
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
path.append(circlePath)
path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
fillLayer.path = path.cgPath
fillLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
fillLayer.opacity = 0.5
view.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)
```

Hope this helps you. Good day.

Answer (score 2):

You can draw oval path like this

```
class CustomOval: UView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
       var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        UIColor.gray.setFill()
        ovalPath.fill()
    }
}
```